# how to stream video to RTMP server(or to youtube) from DJI?

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I need to send live video from a DJI camera to an RTMP server.
I try to find information on how to do this in the DJI sdk documentation, but so far I can not find the answer how to do it.

I would appreciate if you tell me how to do it.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Did you check the [demo on GitHub](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information @Vall0n

Answer (score 0):

For now, no. But it is said that in the next version of DJI Mobile SDK (After v4.8.1), will provide APIs/Samples for developers to implement video live streaming features, includes stream video to RTMP server.